# Find min(yesterday, max(lastlogin, migrationdate))

Tags: java, java-stream, option-type

I can only think of doing this with two streams. Is there a better way?

```
LocalDate lastLoginOrMigrationDate = Stream.of(lastLogin, migrationdate)
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .max(Comparator.comparing(LocalDate::toEpochDay)).orElse(yesterday);

    return Stream.of(lastLoginOrMigrationDate, yesterday)
            .min(Comparator.comparing(LocalDate::toEpochDay)).orElse(yesterday);
```

Comment: Joda-Time library makes things easy? did you try using it?

Comment: Use a third party library.

Comment: @VikramPalakurthi why should he use JodaTime which is old when he is working with java.time api?
"Joda-Time is the de facto standard date and time library for Java prior to Java SE 8. Users are now asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310)."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will do something like this

```
LocalDate result = Stream.of(lastLogin, migration)
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .max(Comparator.comparing(LocalDate::toEpochDay))
            .filter(max -> max.isBefore(yesterday))
            .orElse(yesterday);
```

Question -> Why are you using `toEpochDay` for comparison rather than using the compareTo?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. And yes, good question about compareTo. I guess my only excuse is because its friday and my brain already began the weekend.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, you could take the resulting optional from .max and filter it by .isBefore(yesterday). if the stream is null, then yesterday was before the max of lastLogin and migrationDate, otherwise, the result will be their max

Comment: Just realised after writing my answer that you mentioned the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I accepted @Sneh's answer because it had code. But I upvoted your answer so you get some points anyway :)